# Open file with terminal and close terminal afterwards

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I want to open a file using the terminal on ubuntu.

To have it independent from the terminal, I use gnome-open:

```
gnome-open text.pdf
```

And since I'm lazy, I also have this alias in my .bashrc:

```
alias g='gnome-open'
```

So when I type `g text.pdf` the file opens in evince but here is my problem:

The terminal is still open! I often don't need the terminal at that moment and since I'm using a tiling window manager it's wasting space so I close it manually which is annoying.

Is there a way to automatically close the terminal after the file was opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question but I would use something like `[program] [file-to-be-opened] & exit`. So, if I have a file called `something.txt` and I wanted to open it from a terminal with a GUI-based text editor, Leafpad, and close the terminal, I'd open a terminal and run:

```
leafpad something.txt & exit
```

where `exit` is used to close the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is the command I was looking for. It's not very handy to use since it's a lot of typing but I could build a function for my .bashrc: `function g {gnome-open $1 & exit}`